# XAML ListBox only shows class name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listbox

How do I get my class properties to show up in the ListBox?

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstPlayers" >
     <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player.LastName}"></TextBlock>
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**C#:**

```
public class Player
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}


public void LoadPlayers()
{
    foreach (Player player in Players)
    {
         lstPlayers.Items.Add(player);
     }
}
```

The only thing that shows up in the ListBox is

```
TestApplication1.Player
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have some problems with you current implementation. First, the DataTemplate should be placed inside the ItemTemplate for the `ListBox`. Second, the DataContext for each `ListBoxItem` will be an instance of `Player` so you should bind directly to `FirstName` and `LastName`. Third, the properties in `Player` should be made public for the DataBinding to work.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstPlayers" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```cs
public class Player
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Also, instead of adding the collection item by item to the `ListBox`, just set it as ItemsSource

```
lstPlayers.ItemsSource = Players;
```

Comment: +1 for second point, I could not see because on iPhone StackOverflow does not show scroll for code part and I could only see "{Binding"...

Comment: @Akash Kava: I've been having the same problem on iPhone but I recently noticed that if you tap/press the code with two fingers than you can scroll it. Try it out:)

Comment: thanks so much, it works, too bad no body told me till date !!

Answer (score 1):

DataTemplate should be inside ListBox.ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

set the collection, Players as ItemSource

and

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstPlayers" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the DataType to your DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Player}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

local is the namespace for your TestApplication1.Player. you can set the datatemplate to the listebox.itemtemplate or as a resource of any "parent object"